# Unable debug python helloworld in vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am trying python first time in VSCode.
I am successfully able to run python file, but not able debug it.
I am following steps given in [this tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial#_debugging-hello-world).
When I debug, I am getting following error in Debug console:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/digitate/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2018.1.0/pythonFiles/PythonTools/visualstudio_py_launcher.py", line 91, in <module>
    vspd.debug(filename, port_num, debug_id, debug_options, currentPid, run_as)
```

Comment: For ease of diagnosing, is that the full error message? I would expect the class of the error and error message to also be shown.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when using a vpn from a client.
After closing the software the debug starts working again.
Probably some a problem with the port used by the debugger